# Every instance of <use xlink:href...> animates?

Tags: animation, svg, href, xlink

I'm using the "use xlink:ref" tag to render a polyline that's defined in the "defs" tag and animate it. I want to also use xlink:ref to render the same polyline, but without the animation, i.e., as just a static object. But all three instances of the "use xlink:ref" that I render animate, even though there's no animation associated with two of them!? How can I have only one of the three instances of it animate? I don't understand why SVG thinks I want the other 2 instances to animate. Thanks for any help!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">

  <defs>
  <marker id="mCircle" markerWidth="160" markerHeight="160" refX="80" refY="80" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" style="fill: red; stroke: black; stroke-width: 5px; opacity:0.2"/>
  </marker>

  <marker id="mMid" markerWidth="100" markerHeight="100" refX="50" refY="50" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="6" style="fill: black; stroke: none; stroke-width:4px; opacity:1"/>
  </marker>

  <path d="M 0,0  60,0  120,0  180,0 240,0 300,0 360,0" id="linered" style="marker-start: url(#mCircle); marker-end: url(#mCircle); marker-mid: url(#mMid); stroke-width: 12; fill:none; stroke-linejoin:round; stroke-linecap:round; stroke-opacity: 0.6"/>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#linered" transform="translate(120, 280)" style="stroke-dasharray:222; stroke-dashoffset:-70px; stroke:orange;"/>
  <animate
  xlink:href="#linered"
  attributename="d"
  dur="2s"
  begin="1s;"
  values= "M 0 0,      60 0,     120 0,     180 0,     240 0,     300 0,    360 0;
           M 180 0,    60 40,    120 -30,   180 60,    240 220,   300 60,   180 0;
           M 180 0,    60 -33,   120 60,    180 -90,   240 70,    300 0,    180 0;
           M 180 0,    60 40,    120 -30,   180 60,    240 220,   300 60,   180 0;
           M 0 0,      60 0,     120 0,     180 0,     240 0,     300 0,    360 0;"

  keySplines= "0 0.8 0.3 1;     0 0.8 0.3 1;    0 0.8 0.3 1;    0 0.8 0.3 1;"
  keyTimes=  "0;    0.33;    0.5;    0.66;     1"
  calcMode="spline"        
  repeatcount="4"
  />

  <g transform="translate(300 280)">
    <use id="static1" xlink:href="#linered" x="-180" y="0" transform="rotate(60)"  style="stroke-dasharray:222; stroke-dashoffset:-70px; stroke:blue;"/>

    <use id="static2" xlink:href="#linered" x="-180" y="0" transform="rotate(120)" style="stroke-dasharray:222; stroke-dashoffset:-70px; stroke:white;"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: (For use as a standalone file, attributes are case-sensitive. Therefore I have corrected `markerunits` to `markerUnits`.) Where do you see an animation? This code is a static picture on Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are a few errors in your code concerning upper case letters in attributes. While Chrome seems to be a bit more forgiving (as defined in SVG v2), other browsers still adhere to SVG v1.1, which is fully XML-compliant in this regard. So you should always use case-sensitive `markerUnits`, `attributeName` and `repeatCount` attributes.

Your main problem is *what* you are animating:

```
<animate xlink:href="#linered" attributeName="d" ... />
```

Your animation references the `<path id="linered" />` element, which is the template from which each `<use>` is derived. Each of them copies the whole template, including its animation.

Please note that your `<animate>` tag is a **sibling** to the `<use>` tag it is positioned next to. Both are self-closing tags, and there is no connection between those two exept their placement in the source code next to each other - but that is incitental.

The connection between an element and its animation can only be established in two ways.

1. an `<animate>` element is the child of the animated element (do not use the `xlink:href` attribute for this syntax):

```html
<path ...>
  <animate ... />
</path>
```

2. an `<animate>` element, positioned **anywhere** in the same svg fragment, references the animated element:

```html
<path id="target"... />
<!-- other content -->
<animate xlink:href="#target" ... />
```

If you want to animate one `<use>` element, but not the others, you need to animate that element. For example you could animate a `transform` attribute set on the `<use>` element. But the `d` attribute you want to animate is part of the referenced `<path>` element.

The `<use>` element is no stand-in for what it is referencing, but conceptually a container that hides a copy of its reference inside (in what is called a *Shadow DOM*). This copy cannot be referenced with a url, or a CSS selector. It cannot be animated individually.

The only solution is to write down the element to be animated seperately (note the id):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">

  <defs>
  <marker id="mCircle" markerWidth="160" markerHeight="160" refX="80" refY="80" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" style="fill: red; stroke: black; stroke-width: 5px; opacity:0.2"/>
  </marker>

  <marker id="mMid" markerWidth="100" markerHeight="100" refX="50" refY="50" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="6" style="fill: black; stroke: none; stroke-width:4px; opacity:1"/>
  </marker>

  <path id="linered" d="M 0,0  60,0  120,0  180,0 240,0 300,0 360,0" style="marker-start: url(#mCircle); marker-end: url(#mCircle); marker-mid: url(#mMid); stroke-width: 12; fill:none; stroke-linejoin:round; stroke-linecap:round; stroke-opacity: 0.6"/>
  </defs>

  <path id="linered-animated" transform="translate(120, 280)" d="M 0,0  60,0  120,0  180,0 240,0 300,0 360,0" style="marker-start: url(#mCircle); marker-end: url(#mCircle); marker-mid: url(#mMid); stroke-width: 12; fill:none; stroke-linejoin:round; stroke-linecap:round; stroke-opacity: 0.6;stroke-dasharray:222; stroke-dashoffset:-70px; stroke:orange;"/>
  <animate
  xlink:href="#linered-animated"
  attributeName="d"
  dur="2s"
  begin="1s;"
  values=   "M 0 0,      60 0,     120 0,     180 0,     240 0,     300 0,    360 0;
       M 180 0,    60 40,    120 -30,   180 60,    240 220,   300 60,   180 0;
       M 180 0,    60 -33,   120 60,    180 -90,   240 70,    300 0,    180 0;
       M 180 0,    60 40,    120 -30,   180 60,    240 220,   300 60,   180 0;
       M 0 0,      60 0,     120 0,     180 0,     240 0,     300 0,    360 0;"

  keySplines="0 0.8 0.3 1;     0 0.8 0.3 1;    0 0.8 0.3 1;    0 0.8 0.3 1;"
  keyTimes= "0;    0.33;    0.5;    0.66;     1"
  calcMode="spline"        
  repeatCount="4"
  />

  <g transform="translate(300 280)">
<use id="static1" xlink:href="#linered" x="-180" y="0" transform="rotate(60)"  style="stroke-dasharray:222; stroke-dashoffset:-70px; stroke:blue;"/>

<use id="static2" xlink:href="#linered" x="-180" y="0" transform="rotate(120)" style="stroke-dasharray:222; stroke-dashoffset:-70px; stroke:white;"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

As a footnote only, it seems that the `xlink:href` attribute in an `<animate>` element has a bug in Firefox where the animation is never applied to a referencing `<use>` element.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks! I just still have a hard time conceptually. Only the path attributes (NO animation) are in the <defs> tag. It's odd that <use> tags with NO <animation> tag would animate. I'd think that since they reference the path in the <defs> tag—which DOESN'T have animation—they wouldn't animate unless they also had an <animation> tag. If it worked that way I could apply a different (or no) ani to each <use> of the defined path (like I can apply an x and y to each), instead of creating a redundant path for every ani. Am I making any sense? Is there a clean way to conceptualize this?

Comment: I put the <animation> tag into the <defs>. I hope that's okay, because it works and it is conceptually clearer to me, as it strongly implies that EVERY <use> tag that links to the path in the <defs> that the <animate> tag xlinks to will animate. I had thought that the <animate> tags nested in the <path> that they animated. I just realized that they are not nested, but are separate. This makes things a little clearer...but I still wish it worked my way : ^ ) . Thanks again for your help and time.

Comment: Elaborated a bit on the concept in my answer.