# SVG: How to re-use animated symbol with <use> while varying animation attribute

Tags: svg, svg-animate

Trying to develop some SVG icons as procedurally as possible, thought I'd start with something simple: a fading ellipsis. Got as far as defining and cloning a  comprising a circle with animated opacity. Now trying to figure out how to stagger the animation for each circle with the 'begin' attribute, without having to redefine the entire animation tag. I don't seem to be able to override the 'begin' attribute on a per-use basis. Surely there's a way to do this within the svg  tag without resorting to CSS or Javascript (I'd like to keep the icons self-contained in a .svg file). Code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="100vmin" height="100vmin" viewBox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >

    <symbol id="circle">
        <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.1" animate="#animate">
            <animate id="animate" attributeName="opacity" values="0; 1; 1; 0; 0" keyTimes="0; 0.2; 0.6; 0.8; 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </circle>
    </symbol>

    <use href="#circle" x="-0.4" y="0" />
    <use href="#circle" x="0" y="0" />
    <use href="#circle" x="0.4" y="0" />

</svg>
```

Extensive web searching for a solution to this hasn't turned anything up yet.

Comment: The use tag is not appropriate for what you're trying to do. Just use 3 circles instead.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512647/every-instance-of-use-xlinkhref-animates/46513444#46513444) contains a discussion of the problem, but note the difference: `opacity` is a CSS property, and most CSS properties inherit into the shadow DOM. But `opacity` _never_ inherits and is applied directly to the `<use>` element

Comment: Generate all SVG with **one** Web Component from user defined attributes; but yes, requires JavaScript